Debug in eclipse showing class.class
enter image description hereDebugging in eclipse IDE showing class.class after apply breakpoint and run as Debug option, How to debug it properly?
I tried applying a breakpoint and run as debug option to pinpoint where the error happenes, However its moving to class.class file, instead of I'm expecting a line by line execution where the error happens with the variable section

looks like the source jar missing ?

You are facing a ClassNotFoundException exception which means a class is missing. It would be easier if you just run the code and looking at the error message in the console rather than debugging the code to find out which class is not found. As already said, most likely a JAR is missing in Project > Properties: Java Build Path, tab Libraries.

A ClassNotFoundException exception is being thrown by the code. The debugger is showing you where the exception was thrown - in the java.lang.Class class which is responsible for finding classes.
